# DropdownList binding with is not working in ASP.NET (DateFormat is not coming up in desired way)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, oracle10g

I am using a Oracle Connection to popluate my Dropdownlist. I have created a simple dropdown ASP.NET control and Below is my code through which I am trying to populate it.

```
private void ShowDropDown()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();


            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            string sqlQuery = "select distinct duty_date from duty_rota where  duty_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 300 AND SYSDATE + 300";


            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                    {

                        using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {

                            ODA.Fill(table);

                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
                }

            }

            //DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
            //DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";

            DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "duty_date";
            DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy}";


            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
```

I put the formatting in the below way

```
DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy}";
```

But the DropDownList is displaying data in 10/28/2013 format. Can somebody please help How could I Achieve the formatting of Monday, October 29, 2013 format.

Comment: you have not specify DropDownList1.DataTextField = "field name"; add this, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @HarshilRaval, it works perfectly after adding DataTextField. Please post it as answer. It future it may help others.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have added post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding dropdown we need to set DataTextField and DataValueField. DataTextField is for display purpose and DataValeField is for value purpose(when want to use selected text value).
   Here you forgot to add DataTextField.

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "field name";
```

Hope it helps you.
Thanks.